# Calling a function outside of winForm Function

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code in my WinForm App (C#) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MyProject.Model;

namespace MyProject.WinForm
{
    public partial class EcranLoginAPI : Form
    {
     

        public EcranLoginAPI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void buttonTestConnexion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var test = TestConnexionApi(textBoxApiKey, textBoxApiSecret);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyProject.Model
{
    public class Test
    {

        public bool TestConnexionApi(String apiKey, String apiSecret)

        {
            bool result = false;


            return result;

        }

    }
}
```

I tried everything and I can't figure how to call "TestConnexionApi". The program doesnt recognize the function...

TestConnexionApi is in another folder called Model.

I would appreciate any help ! Thank you. Sorry it is stupid question!

Comment: You're invoking the method as if it were in the same class that's definitely not correct. Is the function marked as static static? You need to include the function definition *in your question*, in order to have a [mcve].

Comment: Hello mason, I improved my post and added code. The function is not static. In other class I can call any function I dont get it. I'm a beginner so I might have done stupid stuff...

Comment: There's many thing that need to be fixed... first, you'll need to create an instance of your Test class in order to call one of it's methods: `var test = new Test()`...  unless you create a static class.

Comment: Oh my god you are right, I forgot to instance my test class... it works now... feels so dumb... sorry and thank you a lot. Do you see any other things that needs to be improved ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to fall into a full tutorial answer so I'll try to keep things as simple as possible:

Your `TestConnexionApi` method has been declared inside a class.  In order to call this method, you have to create an instance of that class:

```
Test myInstance = new MyProject.Model.Test(); //This will create an instance of your Test class
bool result = myInstance.TestConnexionApi(textBoxApiKey, textBoxApiSecret);
```

Another option would be to declare your Test class as static:

```
namespace MyProject.Model
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static bool TestConnexionApi(String apiKey, String apiSecret)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

... and then call the TestConnexionApi method it like this:

```
bool result = MyProject.Model.Test.TestConnexionApi(textBoxApiKey, textBoxApiSecret);
```

If you are getting started in c#, start with some tutorials and make sure to read about static classes.  Many new programmers are abusing the static keyword.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var test = new Test().TestConnexionApi(textBoxApiKey, textBoxApiSecret);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var test = new Test().TestConnexionApi(textBoxApiKey, textBoxApiSecret);
```

Comment: It's not a static function.

Comment: it doesn't have to be static, you can access it this way.

Comment: Well.... you updated your code. Lars comment was right with your original code.